# Alert is not working on Home Page Component

Tags: home-page-component

I have created below Home Page Component. Just to check the alert functionality making URL alert. But , I am not getting the alert on any page. I believe, it should on every page.
Please suggest .

```
<html>
<script>
   var url = window.location.href;
   window.alert(url);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to exec alert after the page is loaded: [onload Event Handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload)

Answer (score 2):

Homepage components run in iframe not from actual window. Instead you should use

```
var url = window.location.href; 
window.parent.window.alert(url);
```

or a simple alert will work as some browser don't allow iframe to access other domain iframe

```
alert('hello');
```

called with the help of parent window. In addition script should be in url page not in home page component edit area.